# write a function in R to loop through an equation and use last value for next round in loop

Tags: r, loops

Using R 3.3.2.

My equation is:

```
  Lt_1<-Lt +(Linf-Lt)*(1-exp(-K))
```

Values for equation parameters:

```
Lt<-40 #only value that changes
Linf<-139.086
K<-0.413
year=c(0:10)
```

I want to loop through the equation for the length of `year` but need to have Lt start as 40, but then take the value of Lt_1 from the last time the equation was calculated.

What I have tried:

```
#dataframe to old output
new<- as.data.frame(matrix( 0, nrow=length(year), ncol= 2))

predict_length<-for(i in seq_along(year)){

                Lt_1<-Lt +(Linf-Lt)*(1-exp(-K))

                new[1,2]<-Lt
                new[i,2]<-Lt_1
                new[i,1]<-data[i]

                }
new
```

Output:

```
  V1       V2
1   0 40.00000
2   1 73.52453
3   2 73.52453
4   3 73.52453
5   4 73.52453
6   5 73.52453
7   6 73.52453
8   7 73.52453
9   8 73.52453
10  9 73.52453
11 10 73.52453
```

The loop isn't working - the second LT_1 is repeated for the remainder of the data frame.

Comment: What is `data[i]`?

Comment: If you are wondering why your loop is not working then reason is behind the fact that `Lt_1` is declared within scope of `for-loop`. You should declare it above `for-loop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `Reduce`, the common higher order function found in other languages, since you are essentially nesting equation calls together:

```
eq <- function(Lt) Lt + (Linf-Lt)*(1-exp(-K))

Lt_1 <- eq(Lt)

Lt_2 <- eq(eq(Lt))

Lt_3 <- eq(eq(eq(Lt)))
```

Hence, wrap `Reduce` inside an `sapply` that iteratively with `rep` passes the input *Lt* values at successively increasing times:

```
new <- as.data.frame(matrix( 0, nrow=length(year), ncol= 2))

new$V1 <- year

new$V2 <- sapply(year, function(i) 
            Reduce(function(x, y) eq(x), rep(40, i+1)))    
new
#    V1        V2
# 1   0  40.00000
# 2   1  73.52453
# 3   2  95.70645
# 4   3 110.38339
# 5   4 120.09456
# 6   5 126.52008
# 7   6 130.77161
# 8   7 133.58468
# 9   8 135.44598
# 10  9 136.67754
# 11 10 137.49241
```

Answer (score 1):

The main question `OP` had raised is about reason why `loop` is not working for him. The main reason is that for all calculations `Lt` has been used in formula. 
The two changes will be needed in `for-loop`:
1. Declare `Lt_1` out of `for-loop`
2. Use `Lt-1` inplace of `Lt1` in formula.

The modified code will be:

```
Lt<-40 #only value that changes
Linf<-139.086
K<-0.413
year=c(0:10)

#dataframe to old output
new<- as.data.frame(matrix( 0, nrow=length(year), ncol= 2))
new[1,1]<- 0
new[1,2]<- Lt
Lt_1 <- Lt;

for(i in 2:length(year)){

  Lt_1<-Lt_1 +(Linf-Lt_1)*(1-exp(-K))
  new[i,2]<-Lt_1
  new[i,1]<- i

}

new
#   V1        V2
#1   0  40.00000
#2   2  73.52453
#3   3  95.70645
#4   4 110.38339
#5   5 120.09456
#6   6 126.52008
#7   7 130.77161
#8   8 133.58468
#9   9 135.44598
#10 10 136.67754
#11 11 137.49241
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty solution:

```
lt0 <- 40

cfunc <- function(lt){
  linf <- 139.086
  k <- 0.413
  lt1 <- lt + (linf-lt)*(1-exp(-k))
}

year = 0:10
val <- c(cfunc(lt0), rep(0, length(year)-1))

for(i in 2:length(year)){
  val[i] <- cfunc(val[i-1])
}
```

output:

```
> val
 [1]  73.52453  95.70645 110.38339 120.09456 126.52008 130.77161 133.58468 135.44598 136.67754 137.49241
[11] 138.03158
```

There ought to be a better way than using a `for` loop